# How to replace variables that have predetermined values with other values?

Tags: java

```
public class stuff {
    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        int n1 = 10;
        int n2 = 4;
        int r = n1%n2;
        System.out.println ( n1 + " " + n2 + " " + r );
        if (r>=1) {
            n2 = n1;
            n1 = r;
            System.out.println ( n1 + " " + n2 + " " + r );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have so far. I want to replace n1 with n2 and n2 with r.

Its giving me this :

```
10 4 2 
2 10 2
```

For the first part, n1 = 10, n2 = 4 and r = 2. For the second part, n1 = 2, n2 = 10 and r = 2. I want for the second part n1 = 4 & n2 = 2. Got any ideas? Explanations would be greatly appreciated even more than code.

Comment: How would you use a variable in math and how would you assign a value to it? And you're already doing it correctly during the variable declarations. I can't understand why you thought that switching the positions of `target` and `source` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want

```
n1 = n2; // this would change n1 from 10 to 4
n2 = r; // this would change n2 from 4 to 2
```

Comment: Seems like that is accurate. Could you explain me to me whats happening in these lines?

Comment: @JackStudentMHS What is there to explain? You are assigning the value of one variable to another variable.

Comment: Thanks a bunch even though its very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand your question, but I'll try to help you.

It's quite simple. The first thing is you want n1 = n2 (n2 at this point is four).

then, n2 = r;

Like this:

```
    public class stuff {
public static void main ( String [] args ) {
    int n1 = 10;
    int n2 = 4;
    int r = n1%n2;
     System.out.println ( n1 + " " + n2 + " " + r );
    if (r>=1) {
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = r;
    System.out.println ( n1 + " " + n2 + " " + r );

    }
}
```

What I think you want to accomplish is a loop though... You want printouts in the console for as long as r is bigger than 1? If that's the case, let me know and I'll explain it to you.